# Solving $z^2=w$ in $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to prove that if $w\in\Bbb C$ then, unless $w$ is a negative real, there's a unique $z\in \Bbb C$ such that $z^2=w$.

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95228/80965), If $w=s\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi), z=r\cos(\theta)+ir\sin(\theta)$ with $z$ some complex number, then:
$$\begin{align}r^2 \cos(2\theta)+ir^2\sin(2\theta)=s\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi) \\
\iff \begin{cases}s\cos(\phi)=r^2 \cos(2\theta)\\
s\sin(\phi)=r^2\sin(2\theta)\end{cases}  \\
\iff \begin{cases}s\cos(\phi)=r^2( \cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))  \\
s\sin(\phi)=r^22\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

I see why $w$ can't be a negative real number, but by this point I'm just lost in the middle of a bunch of trigonometric identities.

Before I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), I thought of this: let's consider $z=a+bi$ and $w=x+yi$, then we have to solve $z^2=w \iff z^2-w=0$, or in other way, $a^2-b^2+2abi-x-yi=0 \\
(a^2-b^2-x)+i(2ab-y)=0 $, but this is pretty much the same as above, and I still don't see much. Maybe because I want both numbers to be the same their modulus should be the same. How do you solve such thing?

(Just out of curiosity, if we consider $f(z)=z^2-w$ as a polynomial in $\Bbb C$, the question would be telling us to prove that this has only one root and not two? If so, this contradicts the [FTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)`:/` )

---

**Edit:**
Please visit this other question: [There is only one $z\in \Bbb C$ such that $z^2=w$ and $Re(z)>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/733380/80965)

Comment: Every $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ has _two_ distinct square roots.

Comment: have you looked at Demoivre's theorem before?

Comment: $(-1)^2=1^2=1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I found this written in some notes, that's why I tried to solve it at first `:/`

Comment: @DavidL yes I have, why? did I used it wrong?

Comment: This is a really bad problem. For every nonzero $ w $ there are two solutions to $ z^2=w $. The problem claims that if we exclude the negative reals then we can choose a *unique* solution that varies continuously with $ w $. It essentially asks you to create a branch of the square root function,  which is an advanced topic better saved until students know some basic complex analysis.

Comment: @GunnarMagnusson could you recommend a good book for dummies? I'm trying to catch up with complex numbers and it seems that the notes that I've got are not the best...

Comment: http://usf.usfca.edu/vca//

Comment: @WillJagy thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any nonzero number, there are always two distinct solutions to $z^2 = w,$ whichever $z$ comes to mind first and then $-z.$

On the other hand, it is possible to define a single valued function on $\mathbb C$ minus the non-positive real axis, by taking the square root of the modulus and dividing the argument by two. Here we take the argument of the original between $-\pi$ and $\pi,$ not including the endpoints. This mapping is sometimes called the principal branch of the square root. It is also the simplest conformal mapping that takes the plane minus the non-positive reals to the (open) right half-plane.

Given the comment thread above, note $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta,$ and we can write any complex number with $r \geq 0$ and, say, $- \pi < \theta \leq \pi$ as $$ w = r e^{i \theta}.$$

People seem to like [Needham's Visual Complex Analysis](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca//).

Comment: Yes... I got very confused

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way to go about solving $z^2=w$. Here's the general framework:

Take the numbers $0,w,|w|$ and $w+|w|$ and plot them in the complex plane; from this you can deduce they form the vertices of a rhombus, and then geometrically that $\arg(w+|w|) = \frac{1}{2}\arg(w)$.

Thus, there exists $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $z=t(w+|w|)$ is a root of $z^2=w$. If you solve for this $t$, you need to take a real square root, which gives rise to the two complex square roots. You'll get a formula for the square roots of $w$ in terms of $w,|w|$ and $\Re(w)$.

(All credit of this solution to Robin Chapman)

Comment: Seeing it like this is actually really pretty, say thanks to Robin Chapman :)