# There is only one $z\in \Bbb C$ such that $z^2=w$ and $Re(z)>0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $w\in\Bbb C$, show that unless $w\in \Bbb R^-$, there exists only one $z\in \Bbb C$ such that $z^2=w$ and $Re(z)>0$.

*This question is related to* [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683875/80965) *other question, but this is a modification of the problem to have a solution.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the complex polynomial equation in the variable $z\colon z^2-w=0.$ It has two distinct  solutions for every non-zero complex constant $w$. Take for $w$  a number that is not  negative real. If the solutions are denoted $a,b$, check that $(a/b)^2= 1$. Or $a=\pm b$. Clearly one of $a$ or $b$ will have positive number as its  real part.